# if the toast has already appeared displays another toast

Tags: android, class, android-activity, android-toast

I wanted to know if there was a way not to get the same message when the user opens the activity, in my activity when it is open you will see a message with the toast if the user returns to the same activity i want to bring up another message the code is :

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.q_050);

  //--> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int    

Bundle value = getIntent().getExtras();
            int num = value.getString("sent").toString();
            if(num){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "next message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.checkpoint), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: you can use intent.putextra() to decide what message to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your first activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.q_050);
    Bundle value = getIntent().getExtras();
    String str= value.getString("sent").toString();
    if(str =="activity_two"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "next message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.checkpoint), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is your second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);//button to return to previous activity
    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                    FirstActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("sent", "activity_two"); //here 1 is a number used in first activity for if else
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I see a problem in this code         Bundle value = getIntent().getExtras();
     int num = value.getString("sent").toString();
     if(num){

Comment: oops sorry you can use Integer.toString(anyStringVariable); i dont have a code editor

Comment: I have edited my answer using String datatype it may contain some errors as I dont have an editor currently.

Answer (score 0):

create a string on activity A :

```
String test = "blahblahblah";
```

create a bundle :

```
Bundle  b = new Bundle();
```

then, put above string to the bundle :

```
b.putString("testing", test);
```

define your activity B :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivityB.class);
```

put your extras bundle :

```
i.putExtras(b);
```

start the activity :

```
startActivity(i);
```